# creating checkboxes in for() loop

Tags: c++, loops, winapi, for-loop, checkbox

I want to create 31 checkboxes in for() loop . My code :

```
for (int i = 1; i<32; i++)
{
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    std::swprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer), L"1", i);
    g_hPrzycisk = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", buffer, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, 
        polozenie, 100, 30, 30, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    polozenie = polozenie + 30;
}
```

ERRORS

```
C:\Users\Komputer\Desktop\grafik\GrafikOnClick\main.cpp In function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':

66  120 C:\Users\Komputer\Desktop\grafik\GrafikOnClick\main.cpp [Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' [-fpermissive]

72  0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\windows.h In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h

1       C:\Users\Komputer\Desktop\grafik\GrafikOnClick\main.cpp                  from main.cpp

1935    26  C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\winuser.h [Note] initializing argument 3 of 'HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)'

28      C:\Users\Komputer\Desktop\grafik\GrafikOnClick\Makefile.win recipe for target 'main.o' failed
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: Please use code tags also in current text: "`"

Comment: I recommend moving the `buffer` definition to before the `for` loop.  This will prevent the variable from being allocated and deleted 32 times.  (Although the compiler *may* do this at different optimization levels.)

Comment: You are mixing ANSI and Unicode in your `CreateWindowEx()` call. The error messages indicate you're still in ANSI mode; you're trying to set the window class as an ANSI string and the control text to a Unicode string.

Comment: Also is `g_hPrzycisk` a single `HWND` or an array of `HWND`s? Your loop as written will only ever store the handle of the last checkbox; you probably want to make `g_hPrzycisk` an array instead.

Answer (score -1):

i can't see the error but these are other errors corrected

```
for (int i = 1; i<32; i++)
{
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    std::swprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(*buffer), L"%d", i);
    //                                                         ^___ corect this
    CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("BUTTON"), buffer, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_CHECKBOX, 
    //                ^^^___ and this (TEXT) macro
    // ^___ you can also drop this 'g_hPrzycisk' (is not an error)

        polozenie, 100, 30, 30, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    polozenie = polozenie + 30;
}
```

Comment: Dropping `g_hPrzycisk` and using `NULL` as the control ID leaves no way of accessing the checkbox. There is a problem with `g_hPrzycisk` though; I already pointed out what above.

Comment: he has to define buttons id and forget about g_hPrzycisk. accessing controls by id is easiest and more practical

Comment: ...no, it's entirely a matter of preference. But that doesn't change that your solution doesn't use IDs either...

Comment: @andlabs you right, i missed there, i think now he got the point.